# How to disable event.preventDefault() if submition is correct?

Tags: javascript, flask, dom-events

I want to redirect to the homepage and flash a message using flask, and I think I need to disable the `preventDefault()` function:

```
    login_form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios.post(login_form.action, {
        username: login_form.username.value,
        password: login_form.pass.value
    }).then((response) => {
        if (response.data["returnval"] === "wrong-crd")
        {
            _alert.innerHTML = "Username or password is incorrect";
            _alert.hidden = false;
        }
        else
        {
            window.location.href = "/";
        }
    });
});
```

The code works but I can't flash a message, how can I disable the `preventDefault()` function.

My flask code:

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("login.html")
    else:
        username = request.json.get("username")
        password = request.json.get("password")
        

    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = %s", (username,))
    returned = cursor.fetchall()

    if len(returned) == 0:
        return jsonify(returnval="wrong-crd")

    if check_password_hash(returned[0][3], password):
        session.permanent = True
        session["userId"] = returned[0][0]
        flash("Logged in!")
        return redirect("/")
    else:
        return jsonify(returnval="wrong-crd")
```

Comment: Maybe your flash message has changed only for that one action, when you have used redirect in your python for your async javascript script it kinda setted your flash message but this "page" is not showed, because response is retruned to javascript. Then you are "refreshing" page and its already gone because it was message for previous page. Its just my bet because I dont work in python and I worked with flash messages in another language.  I think you should return some proper json and not redirect...

Answer (score 0):

Since AJAX is asynchronous, it means that it takes time to get the response after you submit your request.

If you do not prevent default event on the start, it will usually trigger that default event BEFORE you even receive your response.

You can do something like this :

Make a function that will make a popup message, something like this :

```
function pushNotification(message){
   alert(message);
}
```

We are going to be using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store popup messages that need to be shown.
So firstly we are going to add a small code to your main javascript file that will trigger the function that we just made :

```
let nextMSG = localStorage['nextMessage'];
if(nextMSG!=undefined && nextMSG!=""){
    pushNotification(nextMSG);
    localStorage['nextMessage']="";

}
```

Now all you have to do is modify your code so that :

a) - When the response fails(user doesn't log in), you call `pushNotification()` function directly

b) - When the user logs in, you firstly change value of localStorage['nextMessage'] to a value that you want the user to see after redirect, and then redirect the user to wanted location.

Answer (score 0):

You could just call `login_form.submit()` to proceed with the default submission if the field values are correct.

```
login_form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios.post(login_form.action, {
        username: login_form.username.value,
        password: login_form.pass.value
    }).then((response) => {
        if (response.data["returnval"] === "wrong-crd")
        {
            _alert.innerHTML = "Username or password is incorrect";
            _alert.hidden = false;
        }
        else
        {
            login_form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```